# Cannot set icon

Tags: icons, root, mint

When I put file icon.png in to the `usr/share/icons` folder (doing that as root), I can't set that icon on my application latter on. When I try, I navigate to the icons folder, but that icon doesn't work. I can't even see it by navigating to icons folder one more time. I can see it or only open it when I go to the icons folder with root privileges.

This happens on [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 17, 32 bit.

[image]

As you can see, while in regular mode, I can't see the picture, and while in root mode, I can edit it, so how could I be able to set it as my application icon?

Comment: i think this site is only for ubuntu users

Comment: @agharehanabbas - [it is](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) - close voters bear in mind the icon system will work almost exactly the same on many Linux systems....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to permission problem in your png file

try this `sudo  chmod 644 /usr/share/icons/mcicon.png`

For more info about permissions :

http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0070.html

Answer (score 1):

You likely have two problems here

- **Permissions**

  You can do this in Nemo by right-clicking on the file, going to Properties and setting it so the file can be read by 'Other' users.
- Where you put it

  The icon directories sort of work like this (as far as I remember):

  ```
   /usr/share/icons/ICON-THEME/RESOLUTION/TYPE/ICON
  ```

  e.g.

  ```
   /usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/places/user-home.png
  ```

  So you need to resize your icon to the correct resolutions *(`48x48`/`64x64` is usually enough)*, then place it in the correct location *(probably the `apps` folder`in the`gnome`or`hicolor` folder.)* - e.g.

  ```
   /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/mcicon.png
  ```

  Possibly better method include editing the `.desktop` launcher file of the app to have the correct icon path:

  ```
    Icon=/usr/share/icons/mcicon.png
  ```

  And to put any changes you make in your user's home directory e.g. for launchers, in `~/.local/share/applications` *(I think for icons it is  `~/.local/share/icons`)*

<sup>Most of this is off the top of my head as I don't have access to a Linux box at the moment... :(</sup>